# Getting error in Kubernetes cronjob while using google cloud sdk to upload data on GCS bucket

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, hashicorp-vault

```
**Yaml for kubernetes that is first used to create raft backup and then upload into gas bucket**

apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: raft-backup
    numenapp: raft-backup
  name: raft-backup
  namespace: raft-backup
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-addr: https://vault.vault-internal.net:8200
          labels:
            app.kubernetes.io/component: raft-backup
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
              - |
                SA_TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token);
                export VAULT_TOKEN=$(vault write -field=token auth/kubernetes/login jwt=$SA_TOKEN role=raft-backup);
                vault operator raft snapshot save /share/vault-raft.snap;
                echo "snapshot is success"
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
            env:
            - name: VAULT_ADDR
              value: https://vault.vault-internl.net:8200
            image: vault:1.10.9
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: snapshot
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /share
              name: share
          - args:
            - -ec
            - sleep 500
            - "until [ -f /share/vault-raft.snap ]; do sleep 5; done;\ngsutil cp /share/vault-raft.snap\
              \ gs://raft-backup/vault_raft_$(date +\"\
              %Y%m%d_%H%M%S\").snap;\n"
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli:latest
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: upload
            securityContext:
              allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /share
              name: share
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          securityContext:
            fsGroup: 1000
            runAsGroup: 1000
            runAsUser: 1000
          serviceAccountName: raft-backup
          volumes:
          - emptyDir: {}
            name: share
  schedule: '*/3 * * * *'
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 60
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
```

**Error while running gsutil command inside the upload pod**

$ gsutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/configurations/named_configs.py", line 172, in ActiveConfig
return ActiveConfig(force_create=True)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/configurations/named_configs.py", line 492, in ActiveConfig
config_name = _CreateDefaultConfig(force_create)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/configurations/named_configs.py", line 640, in _CreateDefaultConfig
file_utils.MakeDir(paths.named_config_directory)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/files.py", line 125, in MakeDir
os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bundledpythonunix/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bundledpythonunix/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bundledpythonunix/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/cloudsdk/.config'
$ command terminated with exit code 137

Answer (score 1):

`OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/cloudsdk/.config' $ command terminated with exit code 137`

It seems you don't give enought permission in your cronJob.

Try to change :

```
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 1000
  runAsGroup: 1000
  runAsUser: 1000
```

by :

```
securityContext:
  privileged: true
```

Tell me if it works or not and we can discuss about it.

Edit for complete response :

Use this `apiVersion: batch/v1` instead of `apiVersion: batch/v1beta1`

Comment: error validating data: ValidationError(CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.securityContext): unknown field "privileged" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSecurityContext; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: What version of kubernetes do you use ?

Comment: 1.23.14 gke https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.23.md#v12315

Comment: Use this `apiVersion: batch/v1` instead of `apiVersion: batch/v1beta1`

Comment: that's work..but I also have PSP on cluster so need to create rolebindings for that to allow privileged...but it works now ..thanks @sbrienne